# WCF Service On Linux failed to communicate with Client on Windows by NetTcp

Tags: wcf, mono, nettcpbinding

There

**Context:** 
I write a demo console app -a WCF service which running on Linux by mono, and a console Client which running on Windows 7.

Linux Versoin: Both on Ubuntu and Match-box

Mono Version: 2.10.8.1(On Ubuntu) and 2.10.6(On Match-box)

**Issue:**
 The client could communicate with Service by basicHttpBinding **but NOT** netTcpBinding.

**Exception Info:**
Could not connect to net.tcp://192.168.1.220/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:14.0408031. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.1.220:808.

**Service Code:**

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        try
        {
            ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(DynIPService.DynIPService));
            //sh.AddServiceEndpoint("DynIPServiceContract.IDynIPService", binding, "net.tcp://10.161.66.213:808");
            sh.Open();
            foreach (var ep in sh.Description.Endpoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}, ListenUri: {1}, ListenUriMode: {2} ", ep.Address, ep.ListenUri, ep.ListenUriMode);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Service is running");               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Service app.config**(partial, here i just list the endpoints and bindings)

```
<services>
  <service name="DynIPService.DynIPService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:808"  
              binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCP_Binding"
              contract="DynIPServiceContract.IDynIPService"/>
    <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:123"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HTTP_Binding"
              contract="DynIPServiceContract.IDynIPService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HTTP_Binding">
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding  name="TCP_Binding">
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Client Code:**

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var ip = "localhost.localdomain";
        var ip = "192.168.1.220";

        //Tcp
        Binding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        var tcpUri = new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:808", ip));

        //http
        Binding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();  
        var httpUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:123",ip));

        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(httpUri.ToString());
        IDynIPService proxy = ChannelFactory<IDynIPService>.CreateChannel(httpBinding, address);
        var hostIP = proxy.ReadHostIp();
        Console.WriteLine(hostIP);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using different IP addresses on client and server?  Try setting both to either 127.0.0.1 (if client and server are on the same machine) or that 192.168.x.y.  If that doesn't help, then it's also possible that NetTcp is buggy on Linux, I'll have a look next week.

Comment: because of client anf server ara different machine,

Comment: i use the different IP succeed by basic http, and others on stackoverflaw succeed by nettcp,but their issue is different from me

Comment: Maybe I'm confused here, but the services app.config from your question uses 127.0.0.1 and you attempt to connect to it remotely from another machine.  But the service won't listen on an address that's visible on the network, so you should get a connection refused.  If that really works with http, then that's a bug (which will be fixed early next week, so don't rely on this broken behavior). Make sure your app.config uses the server machines IP address that's visible on the network, ie. 192.168.1.220.

Comment: Whatever the IP set to 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.220, I use the netstat -ant to check the listening port on Ubuntu, for NETTCP,it always be 127.0.0.1:808. For HTTP it always be 0.0.0.0:123. And the Client could communicate with server by HTTP but now NETTCP. I guess there should be some incorrect configuration on Ubuntu, like the /etc/hosts

Comment: Ok, so the HTTP behavior is broken.  It should not listen at 0.0.0.0 and it won't do so anymore in future Mono versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the IP address of your host machine that's publicly visible on the network if you want to connect to it remotely using net.tcp.

I just tested this on Windows and net.tcp and http actually behave differently when using `127.0.0.1`: while HTTP always seem to listen on all interfaces regardless of which IP address you use on your endpoint, using a specific IP such as `127.0.0.1` makes NetTCP only listen on that particular address.

However, you can use `net.tcp://localhost:<port>/<path>` to make it listen on all interfaces (this was was implemented in Mono 2.10.10, see [bug #275](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=275)).

So either use `net-tcp://localhost:808/` in your `app.config` to listen on all interfaces or explicitly set it to a specific IP address (that's publicly visible on the network) using `net-tcp://192.168.1.200:808/` (or whatever the machine's IP address is).

Comment: Martin, Once I use the machine IP that's publicly visible on the networking for the address of EndPoint in the app.config, it always prompt expcetion:"No such host is known",but when I add one record

Comment: 192.168.1.220 xxxxxxxx to the /etc/hosts file. It does worked! I think it is bug that have been fixed in bug report you mentioned before. But i want to know which version of mono fixed the bug.thanks

Comment: Another try: I upgrade the mono version from 2.10.6 to 2.10.8.1.Then modify the IP in app.config to current machine IP(192.168.1.220), no need to change the /etc/hosts file.It does works. But modify the IP in the app.config to localhost, the listening URL is 127.0.0.1, so it doesnot work.

Comment: Bug #275 (make "localhost" in `app.config` listen on all interfaces) has been fixed on Sep 5th, commit d9ba2c3 in the mono-2-10 branch, so this should be 2.10.10.

I don't see any technical need why a DNS lookup would be required, so throwing an exception when you don't have the IP address in your `/etc/hosts` sounds broken to me.  But that's not happening anymore with 2.10.8.1, right ?

Comment: Turns out I was actually wrong here, net.tcp's behavior is different from http's.  I fixed my answer.

Comment: Martin, where can I find the source code or release build of 2.10.10, it seems that the latest version is 2.10.9 from mono-project.com. Thanks.

Comment: Just get it from github. 2.10 is based on the [mono-2-10 branch](https://github.com/mono/mono/commits/mono-2-10)

Comment: Hi, @MartinBaulig, I cannot find the 2.10.10 from github.com. And I download the 3.0.2 source code from mono-project.com and compile it on Ubuntu. Modify the IP to "localhost" ,and it seems that the server and client established connection , but get a another exception:

Comment: **This request operation sent to net.tcp://192.168.1.199/ did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.** But basichttpbinding works well.

Comment: Even so I increase the sendTimeout to 2 minutes on Client the exception as the same as before but timeout(0:02:00).

Comment: I don't think so it is an networking or server/client machine performance issue.I guess there still are some problem on NETTCPBINDING on mono,right?

Comment: Today, I copy the client to the Linux machine which running the service, the client works well by nettcpbinding

Comment: And It seems that the client also work well on another Linux machine.Anyway, the client on the Windows does not works well with Service on the Linux. I do not know the reason.

Comment: Finally I found the resolution according to another notes, just change the port from 808 to 8080(All >4000 port is OK). Thanks @MartinBaulig so much for these days kindly help!